# Strange Windows update issue

Tags: windows-registry, windows-update

I'm trying to restore my missing Windows Update service.
All the tutorials out there [[1]](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-missing-update-service/)
[[2]](https://www.minitool.com/news/fix-windows-update-service-missing.html) [[3]](https://www.wintips.org/fix-windows-10-update-service-is-missing/) [[4]](https://www.technewstoday.com/fix-windows-update-service-missing-error/) say the same thing:

> Get this `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv` from another computer, and paste on the damaged computer

(Most of the tutorials even offer a version of the reg)

Alright. It imports successfully. I navigate to this key after importing, and it's there.
**But it disappears after I reboot**

Can anyone guess why, and how to fix it ?

SFC and DISM did not work.
In place upgrade is not a solution: changes all my settings/personalizations and defaults.

**Information:**
**Windows 10 22H2** compilation **10.0.19045.2604**;
Windows update error code **0x80070424**.

I really can't remember how did this happen... One random day I was going to check updates, and there it was this error code.

Update: Windows Repair tool from Tweaking.com ran successfully, but did not repair the problem.

Thank you all.

Comment: You're starting the question with the issues you have with an attempted fix, aka [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but what are the details of the issue you're having (what Windows version do you have and what do you see when trying Windows Updates)? Also, all the guides you linked have more steps/fixes than just the registry one you mentioned in details, but you don't write in details what exactly doesn't work with them for you (just one example, an in-place Upgrade actually doesn't change any normal system settings.)

Comment: Care you explain how you lost or broke Windows Update originally? Depending on how you disabled Windowed Update, performing an in-place upgrade, might be your only solution

Comment: Try a Windows Repair Install. That will very likely fix the update issue

Comment: @Yisroel Tech: Is it really relevant to know the windows version? Update the thread anyway to add this information and try to answer the questions. The SFC and DISM did not work because both of them finished without finding errors. If no solution come up, I will resort to the full repair. I can't remember what exactly the repair messes up with, but I stopped using it long ago because it does mess with something. Really can't remember what right now... Thank you all for the answers so far.

Comment: As you state, the solution *is* to reinstall Windows from ISO. Make a drive image first, just in case, but usually reinstall, saving current files, does no harm (other than  reinstalling unwanted apps and services, which you can remove afterwards... *with care*).

Comment: @LucasBS, of course it's important, Windows 7 or 8 doesn't have the same good in place upgrade as Windows 10 and 11, and we need to know if the fixes you attempted were for tg correct version of Windows. In **Services** do you see the Windows Update service? And if you do what's the status of it, and if not running can you start it there?

Comment: Hello @Yisroel Tech. **Services.msc** is the first place I look when Windows Update gives off an error message. And there it was. Or **there it wasn't: The service is simply not there**. That is when I googled for "missing windows update service", ending on those infinite all-equal tutorials/fixes cited on the opening thread. I'd really like to know how to fix the error instead of patching and forgetting. As a side question, why windows simply erases the registry entry that supposedly fixes it.

Comment: Why it erases it? The same reason it went missing in the first place. While we don't know what that reason is, it's most certain it was something you did on the machine (not realizing the side effect) it's just not easy to know what it is, especially without full access to check everything on your computer (for a start I'd check all installed programs, all startup things, all group policies, and task schedules.) But I think it's all a waste, since the first thing to try should be an in-place upgrade, which really doesn't delete any normal "settings/personalizations and defaults"